# Updating existing records in a Salesforce Object after creating a new validation rule or trigger or Workflow Rule

Tags: validation-rule, data-loader, administration

Do I need to delete and insert all the existing records again into the Salesforce object via a Dataloader, after creating a new Trigger or a new Validation Rule or a new Workflow Rule to clean the bad data?
Example of existing bad data:
Existing record in the Salesforce object:
Candidate experience: 3 years
Desired Job: Engineering Manager

Validation Rule Applied: Candidate_Experience < 5 && Desired_Job= 'Engineering Manager'
Error message: 'Candidate needs to have a minimum of 5 years experience to apply for the position of Engineering Manager'

Comment: Why not just run a report to show all records that don't meet the criteria, then  update or delete needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually It's depends on the data usage factor of your SFDC org for that particular object records.

- If those data's are having very less usage.. Yes, You can delete the existing data and leave the valid data into your org.
- If the data's usage in daily routine is very high, Please create a check box field like `Active` and use the data loader to enable the active check box field for on valid data only and continue to work on those data only.y using this field, We can provide some diff. of our valid and invalid data to user*)

[*Update that check box field also into your `Validation rule`,`Trigger`,`Work flow` to avoid the inactive records get updated/processed* **and** *After sometime you can delete those inactive records once after confirmed as it's not used by your end users*].

**Note: Data volume also sometime will need to considered before you decide to execute `Deletion` option for your Invalid data. So please take that also on your analysis.**

Hope it will give some idea to you.

Thanks.